# Best way to get detailed apex error/exception from destination organisation of managed package

Tags: exception, package, salesforce

We are developing an application in salesforce which would be available soon in app-exchange.Is there any best way to get detailed error/exception from apex code of package org to owner of managed package so that in next version we can resolve this issue?
P.S. --> I know there is a setup to get unhandled exception but is there any way to get other errors/exception than unhandled exceptions?

Comment: What would be an example of an error that you want to receive other than an unhandled exception?

Comment: @DavidReed Any other DML operation error,Null pointer,Mixed DML,Apex CPU Time Limit,List has now row assignment etc. general errors in apex